# How to save an input data stream to a performing data structure for sql queries in Spark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, spark-streaming

i'm new in the word of bigdata. My goal is to maintain an input data stream in some kind of data structures to perform queries and aggregation operations on them. 
Having as input a continuous data streaming, through the Structured Streaming of spark, I store it in a DataFrame. My questions are:

- is a DataFrame a volatile data structure?
- In case the program crashes, is the DataFrame maintained?
- Is a DataFrame distributed on the various nodes of the cluster or is it kept on the node that executes the code?
- Is it possible to create index on a Dataframe to speed up the response of some queries?

Comment: This looks like very broad questions to me. I recommend looking into some Spark tutorials first and come back with a specific question on code snippets here.

Answer (score 0):

If your are planning to use Spark 2.4+ then go with Dataframes

- Yes DataFrame are volatile they vanish once Spark job finishes but you can save them to Disk as Parquet files and query them later via SPARK / HIVE ro any tool which can read parquet file format.
- In case the program crashes, the DataFrame is not recoverable unless you happen to save them before crash which you can read later once your Spark job is up again.
- Data Frame is distributed Data structure used and understood by Spark. So yes it is partitioned/split across Spark nodes.
- Data frame has partitions to tune the query performance and minimize data shuffling.

Apart from above points Spark has inbuilt check pointing mechanism to make sure there is no data loss when your job crashes. Detail doc can be found on Spark